# Spark Standalone Cluster :Configuring Distributed File System

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have just moved from a Spark local setup to a Spark standalone cluster. Obviously, loading and saving files no longer works.

I understand that I need to use Hadoop for saving and loading files.
My Spark installation is spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

**Question 1:**
Am I correct that I still need to separately download, install and configure Hadoop to work with my standalone Spark cluster?

**Question 2:**
What would be the difference between running with Hadoop and running with Yarn? ...and which is easier to install and configure (assuming fairly light data loads)?

Comment: You could use NFS, GlusterFS, Ceph, S3 or many other shared filesystems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1. Right. The package you mentioned is just packed with hadoop client with specified version and still you need to install hadoop if you want to use hdfs.

A2. Running with yarn means you're using resource manager of spark as yarn. (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-across-applications) So, when the case you don't need DFS, like when you're only running spark streaming applications, you still can install Hadoop but only run yarn processes to use its resource management functionality.